# Having an issue centering image?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to center my image "Logo_Home.svg" on my page but for some reason it isn't working and is sitting in the top left hand corner. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

EDIT 1

I just added the class to the image tag as I forgot it but it still isn't centered vertically just horizontally. Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT 2

Example of what it is i'm trying to achieve.
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://pa2.site.com/IMAGES/Background.svg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid #2f8fcb;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

img.center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>REGISTER</li>
  <li>LOGIN</li>
</ul>

<img src="http://pa2.site.com/IMAGES/Logo_Home.svg" class="center">
```

Comment: you have img.center but you do not have class in img tag. <img class="center" src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Logo_Home.svg">

Comment: Just updated the post, still isn't quite right?

Comment: you can add padding-top: 20px; to make it better. not sure if that will work for you. can you add an image what you r expecting

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt this would work for me as when the viewing device changes the screen size will differ and then the site will be displayed incorrectly. I've also added an image of an example to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Background.svg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid #2f8fcb;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.contain {
  padding-top:20%;
}
img.center{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>REGISTER</li>
  <li>LOGIN</li>
</ul>

<div class="contain">
<img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Logo_Home.svg" class="center">
</div>
```

I put your img inside a div to center vertically using margin-top

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get what you're looking for:

```
ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

img.center {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/BRPrZN)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using flex-box to solve this and it seems to have done the trick.
I started by wrapping the image in a div with the class of center.  I then applied this CSS to achieve the centered content:

```
div.center{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:70vh;
  width:90vw;
}
```

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz6u5qfw/) .